# MvcHtmlString.Create method on Google Chrome to add style - Asp.net

Tags: css, asp.net, google-chrome, razor, model-view-controller

I am trying to add style string to change css values. Despite google chrome doesnt work, firefox works well...

What is the problem?

```
string style = string.Concat("<style type=\"text / css\" ...some css values>
@MvcHtmlString.Create(style);
```

Comment: Try `@Html.Raw(style)`

Comment: I solved my problem using inline css. Thank you.